# NSNotificationCenter called twice in ViewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsnotificationcenter, jasidepanels

I'm using [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) with storyboards in my aplication and also using `NSNotificationCenter`

The problem is that:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(msgResponder:) 
                                         name:@"leftPanelMsg" object:nil];
```

It's being **called twice** inside `viewDidLoad` one call when the `storyboard` is going to be displayed `CenterViewController` and the second one, when I reveal the left panel `LeftViewController`,  I'm using the same class for both, is there a way to stop this?

I've tried the bellow code but is not working,

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                        name:@"leftPanelMsg"
                                                      object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(msgResponder:) 
                                                        name:@"leftPanelMsg" 
                                                      object:nil];
```

Also I used a `bool` to exec the code just 1 time, I turn `mustRun` bool to `NO` when code was executed for first time (`leftPanelMsg`), but at the next notification when `leftPanelMsg` is called again `mustRun` return it's value to true, don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that library provides a view controller extension which answers `sidePanelController`.  So your vc's can ask directly...

```
#import "UIViewController+JASidePanel.h"
// ...

if (self.sidePanelController.centerPanel == self) {
    // observe notification
}
```

or you can ask:

```
if (self.sidePanelController.leftPanel == self) // ... and so on
```

Comment: Thank you, hmmm Indeed I'm using `UIViewController+JASidePanel.h` I put that `if` statement inside `ViewDidLoad` of `myViewController.m` but the code inside this `if` it's also being called twice :(

Comment: Do you mean both the side and center view controller are == self.sidePanelController?  That can't be the case.

Comment: Both have the same class `myViewController.m` in their `Storyboard` but a different `Storyboard Id`, `centerViewcontroller` and `leftViewController`

Comment: The first call is when `centerView` is displayed and the second call occurs when I open the left pannel

Comment: Sure.  Same class, but different *instances*.  We're comparing to self, and only one of those "selves" is in the center position.  Since there are two instances of a vc, you *will* see viewDidLoad called twice, but only one of them should satisfy the condition.

Comment: 1 for explanation :) danh, but both are satisfying the condition :s

Comment: There is also a warning:
`Comparison of distinct pointer types ('JASidePanelController *' and 'myViewController*')`

Comment: Ah.  I'm reading the code in that library now.  The sidePanelController property answers a *container vc*.  The container provides handles to the center left and right vcs.  Please see edit.  (I only read the extension header before, and guessed -- incorrectly -- what that extension property meant).